# strdup() memory leak in structure

Tags: c, memory-leaks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
};

struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(who != NULL);

    who->name = strdup(name);
    who->age = age;
    who->height = height;
    who->weight = weight;

    return who;
}

void Person_destroy(struct Person *who)
{
    assert(who != NULL);

    /*free(who->name);*/
    free(who);
}

void Person_print(struct Person *who)
{
    printf("Name: %s\n", who->name);
    printf("\tAge: %d\n", who->age);
    printf("\tHeight: %d\n", who->height);
    printf("\tWeight: %d\n", who->weight);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // make two people structures
    struct Person *joe = Person_create(
                                       "Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);

    struct Person *frank = Person_create(
                                         "Frank Blank", 20, 72, 180);

    // print them out and where they are in memory
    printf("Joe is at memory location %p:\n", joe);
    Person_print(joe);

    printf("Frank is at memory location %p:\n", frank);
    Person_print(frank);

    // make everyone age 20 years and print them again
    joe->age += 20;
    joe->height -= 2;
    joe->weight += 40;
    Person_print(joe);

    frank->age += 20;
    frank->weight += 20;
    Person_print(frank);

    // destroy them both so we clean up
    Person_destroy(joe);
    Person_destroy(frank);

    return 0;
}
```

`strdup()` is to return a name in `Person_create` structure. But, I'm confused at a point that If it is freed by `free(who);`, all memory should be freed. But not. If that also get freed by `free(who->name);` all heap blocks are freed. Why `free(who);` is not enough to free all heap ?

Comment: C isn't much of an object-oriented language. How would `free()` know to free a member-variable of a struct when it explicitly doesn't know what kind of object it frees, since it takes a `void*` as an argument?

Comment: That's because C is not an object oriented programming , so what that who is really , it's just a block of memory that  points to other places , when you delete who you are only deleting that struct without deleting the member that it points to .

Comment: If you think this is a problem, you might want to check out C++ instead. (*running for cover*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comments to your answer handle your question, but I'll answer more formally.

There is a rule of thumb here: Have as many frees as mallocs. You are missing one free. Referring to the documentation for strdup():

> The strdup() function shall return a pointer to a new string, which is
>   a duplicate of the string pointed to by s1. The returned pointer can
>   be passed to free(). A null pointer is returned if the new string
>   cannot be created.

This isn't the best documentation I've ever seen, but the fact that "The returned pointer can be passed to free()" should tell you that malloc is used under the hood.

So the reason the memory is not being freed is because you're simply not freeing it all. You have a malloc on two lines:

```
struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

and

```
who->name = strdup(name);
```

Elaborating further: What does malloc do? It allocates bytes of memory. Assume pointers are 4 bytes, chars are 1 byte, and ints are 4 bytes.

When you say

```
struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

struct Person has a pointer (4 bytes) and three ints (12 bytes). You are allocating 16 bytes total. Calling free on this will only free those 16 bytes.

Now say we have this line:

```
who->name = strdup("Bob");
```

strdup("Bob") creates a new char* using malloc with 3 chars for a total of 4 bytes because of `/0`.

In total, you have 16 bytes allocated for the struct, and 4 bytes allocated from strdup(), but calling free on "who" only frees 16 bytes. You still have the 4 bytes left over from strdup().